# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}\prod_{i=2}^n(\sqrt{i-1})+2\sum_{i=2}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$ using Weierstrass inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

> Use [Weierstrass's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_product_inequality) to prove that
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \prod_{i = 2}^n (\sqrt{i-1}) + 2 \left(\sum_{i = 2}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\right).$$

Using Weierstrass's inequality, I get

$$1 + \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}} \le  \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \left(\prod_{i = 1}^n (1 + \sqrt{i})\right)$$

Comment: The very same question has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147064/use-weierstrass-inequalities-to-prove-that?rq=1), so please use [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) to search *before* you ask, to see if your question (likely a homework problem if two people ask it in such a short time frame) has been ask before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
Since
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} = 1 + \sum_{k = 2}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}},
$$
we can rewrite the inequality, which has to be shown (by subtracting $2 \sum_{k = 2}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$ from both sides) as 
$$
1 - \sum_{k = 2}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \prod_{k = 2}^n (\sqrt{k-1}).
$$
By the Weierstrass inequality (since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \in (0,1]$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$) we have
$$
1 - \sum_{k = 2}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}
\le \prod_{k = 2}^{n} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\right)
= \prod_{k = 2}^{n} \frac{\sqrt{k} - 1}{\sqrt{k}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \prod_{k = 2}^{n} (\sqrt{k}-1),
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \prod_{k = 2}^{n} \sqrt{k - 1}
$$
where the last equality is achieved by pulling out the denominator out of the product and the last inequality is using the fact that $\sqrt{k}-1 \le \sqrt{k - 1}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_{>1}$, which you can easily verify either by induction or by drawing a graph.